# Async, Callbacks, Closure, Oh My

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dom, asynchronous

Here's what I'm trying to do, and failing miserably at:

I have a MongoDB filled with GPS readings from a device attached to a car. The readings are timestamped and have a lat/lng.

For each reading, I want to create a Position class that contains location, timestamp and some other information.

To plot this on Google Maps, I want to create a Route class, which is made up of an array of Positions Objects.

The main function at the top loads a route from a sample JSON file (to avoid CSRF problems... another story), creates the Position objects and route object fine. The problems start when I try to plot the route.

```
var positions = this.getPositions();
```

If I type

```
console.log(positions);
```

right below that line, it will print the positions array fine. It takes a bit to do that since it's large, but it works.

If however, I type

```
console.log(positions[0]);
```

it wont work because the positions haven't loaded yet.

What do I do?

I'm using classy.js from http://classy.pocoo.org but I've verified this isn't a problem with that.

```
function main()
{
    var route = Route('20120928_025650_0');
    route.plot();
}
var Route = Class.$extend({
    __init__ : function(imaging_run_id)  {
        this.imaging_run_id = imaging_run_id;
        this.positions = [];
        this.load();
    },

    getPositions : function() {
        return (this.positions);
    },

    load : function() {
        //var url='http://localhost:5001/gps/by_imaging_run_id/' + this.imaging_run_id;
        var test_url = '/static/20120928_025650_0.json';
        var me = this;
        $.getJSON(test_url, function(route) {
            for(var position in route) {
                var obj = route[position];
                var new_position = Position(obj['_id'], obj['lat'], obj['lng'], obj['timestamp'], obj['epoch_timestamp'], obj['is_valid']);
                me.pushPositions(new_position);
            }
            me.orderPositions();
        })
        .error(function(jqXhr, textStatus, error) {
            alert("ERROR: " + textStatus + ", " + error);
        });
    },

    orderPositions : function() {
        var unsorted_array = this.getPositions();
        var sorted = unsorted_array.sort(function(a,b){ //Custom sort function
            return a['timestamp'] - b['timestamp']; //Sort ascending
        });
        this.setPositions(sorted);
    },

    plot : function() {
        var positions = this.getPositions();
        var points = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for(var i=0; i<positions.length; i++)
        {
            var obj = positions[i];
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(obj['location'][0], obj['location'][1]);
            points.push(point);
            bounds.extend(point);
        }
        // Create the polyline.
        var route = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: points,
            strokeColor: '#e81971',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 4
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        route.setMap(map);
    }
});

var Position = Class.$extend({
    __init__ : function(id, lat, lng, timestamp, epoch_timestamp, valid)  {
        this.id = id;
        this.location = [lat, lng];
        this.timestamp = new Date(timestamp);
        this.epoch_timestamp = new Date(epoch_timestamp);
        this.valid = valid;
        this.anchor_location;
    },.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you will want to do something like this:

```
var positions = this.getPositions(function(positions) {
    console.log(positions[0]);
});
```

That is, you'll want to write "getPositions" in a way that it accepts a single callback parameter which is invoked once the positions have loaded successfully, and is passed the positions array. In `getPositions` you could check if the positions have already been loaded, and if so, directly invoke the callback. Otherwise, you'll add them to a queue of callbacks (e.g. `this.positionsLoadedCallbacks`), through which you iterate after all positions have been loaded (I think that would be somewhere in your `load` function near `me.orderPositions()`).

For example, your `getPositions` function might look like this:

```
getPositions : function(callback) {
    if(this.positions !== null) {
        callback(this.positions);
        return;
    } 

    this.positionsLoadedCallbacks.push(callback);
},
```

Somewhere after you are sure the positions have been loaded (i.e. in the loadJSON success callback) you'll need to put something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < this.positionsLoadedCallbacks.length; i++) {
    this.positionsLoadedCallbacks[i](this.positions);
}
```

And don't forget to initialize `this.positionsLoadedCallbacks` :)

## console.log trivia

The reason that `console.log(positions)` works and `console.log(positions[0])` does not is easy: if you pass an object reference to `console.log`, the object will be inspected when you click on the little "expand" arrow and try to take a look *inside* the object/array. By the time you click that arrow, the positions have been loaded, of course. However, if you pass a specific array element (e.g. `positions[0]`) it will directly try to look that value up, find that it is still `undefined`, and record that result in the console.

Try it yourself:

```
var i = [];
console.log([i]);
i.push(123);
```

The previous snippet, in chrome 24, shows `[Array[0]]` in the console, but when I expand it, it tells me that the array as `length: 1` and that its first element is `123`

Comment: So for now, that function is simply "return (this.positions)". What would I put inside it instead?

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this all around? I feel like this is becoming a mess quickly.

Comment: No, I don't think there is an easier way to do this. This is pretty much how JavaScripts async facilities work, and you get used to them. I myself find them to be superior to than asynchronous execution concepts in other languages (Ja *cough* va)

Comment: @x3ro How is this any different than equivalent Java code using [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)s?

Comment: @millimoose: Maybe my general dislike of Java got me carried away there :D You are, of course, correct, the concept is the same, however it does require more boilerplate code because of the lack of closures, does it not?

Comment: @x3ro Anonymous inner classes can read `final` local variables from their enclosing method scope. All non-`static` inner classes can also read and write fields of their enclosing class. Now, what you *can't* do is update a local variable that's being used in an AIC "closure", but this sounds like it's more of an impediment to metaprogramming than async code. So the boilerplate you're left with is flipping values of local variables into `final` ones, and the need to create classes for the async callback parameters, but the latter isn't really specific to how Java does async.

Comment: Would using a framework like backbone or ember help make this sort of stuff easier to code?

Comment: @PhilSalesses: I don't think so. You could, for example, use `Backbone.Events` to create a "positionsLoaded" event, but that doesn't really make the whole construct easier.