# JS Framework to deal with asynchronous flow, callbacks and closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I dislike JavaScript. Greatly. I think it's a messy language, though I'll be the first to admit this may be because I don't know how to code in it as well as other languages.

I wasted the last three days dealing with bugs that all stemmed from my poor understanding of asynchronous control flow, callback functions and closure.

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to program in JS so that I can return to productivity.  My current stack is Flask, MongoDB, JQuery and Bootstrap. Ideally I'd like to augment and not replace those.

What framework or tools would be able to best mitigate the JS issues I outlined above?

Comment: What language background are you coming from? This might help with some of your frustrations / unmet expectations in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you learn how to use [jQuery Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).  They aren't required in order to program cleanly with asynchronous functions, but they might be the tool that you're looking for to provide some direction and structure.

We could offer more specifics if you showed some code examples that seem messy to you.

When I have callback functions that have more than 10-15 lines of code, I break them out into a named function and give it a name that describes what it does.  In some cases, I even make it a method on an existing object.  For example, in an API, I use that has an ajax all for logging in, I have a method called `ProcessLoginResponse()` that processes the login response from the ajax call.  If the login succeeds, then this method has to then issue another API call and I create another method on the same object that processes the response to that ajax call to continue the flow.  I document with comments how the flow works, but the appropriately named methods make the code seem clean and easy to know where to set breakpoints or make modifications.

Comment: I have another thread that outlined my latest problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020997/async-callbacks-closure-oh-my In it, I had the closure problem solved in the line "var me = this" but now with the callbacks, it seems like the organization I was shooting for is disappearing rapidly.

Comment: @PhilSalesses, that example looks like you just don't understand that asynchronous operations finish some time later and you HAVE to code with callbacks.  You can't do sequential programming when you have an asynchronous function.  jQuery Deferreds will provide some structure to the callbacks if you want to learn that.

Comment: How can I keep callbacks organized without having them spawn all over the place?

Comment: @PhilSalesses - did you look at jQuery Deferreds yet?  Callbacks don't spawn all over the place.  Each callback has a purpose.  If you're doing a lot of successive asynch operations, you won't have simple sequential code.  You will have a series of callbacks, but if each callback is organized to accomplish a particular task based on the response it receives or even a method on an object, the code can actually be quite organized.  It's something you learn.  But, when you have lots of asynch operations, you have to learn how to code cleanly for asynch ops.  It can be done, but it's different.

Comment: @PhilSalesses - I added a little more about how I do my callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/infinitycbs/jflow

It's a framework that's good at handling asynchronous tasks in node.js and in the browser. It also handles component structures with Static, Public and Private members like traditional OOP.